# User-defined constant types in VBA

Tags: vba

I would like to define a custom data type in VBA and use it to create some user-defined constants. For example:

```
Public Type Person
    Name as String
    Age as Integer
End Type

Public Sub CreatePerson
    Dim singer as Person
    singer.Name = "John"
    singer.Age = 37
End Sub
```

I would like to make `singer` to be constant which will be visible in other subroutines/functions in the same module. Is it possible? If not, how is the best way to store constant values which are connected to each other (like in the example above where `Name` is connected to `Age`)?

Comment: Create `singer` as a Global variable.  It can't be a Constant though, since its value can't be known at compile time.  You'll have to populate it at some point in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.

Code in a module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Type Person
    Name As String
    Age As Integer
End Type


Private cvsinger As Person

Public Function singer() As Person

    Static ConstantHasBeenSet  As Boolean

    If Not ConstantHasBeenSet Then
        cvsinger.Name = "John"
        cvsinger.Age = 37
    End If

    singer = cvsinger

End Function

Public Sub CreatePerson()

    Debug.Print singer.Name, singer.Age

End Sub
```

This is a fairly trivial case, but when the code to find the default values takes longer to process the use of ConstantHasBeenSet becomes worthwhile

(Note that I would also use a similar technique for setting default values for properties in a class)